# C sfunction and NaN

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

hello every body I wrote some codes as Mfiles and used Matlab function to generate an auto S function,every thing was good but for some reasons I was forced to write C sfunction on my own.
now the problem is this: I just translated the codes to C and they are ok in visual studio but when I use them in my sfunction ,I have some invalid answers. (NaN).
I checked the 1st place which my answer becomes NaN and I found that it's when it wants to run my QR decomposition code.
a & b are `doubles` and when `a=-0.00000` & `b=0.000000` it returns NaN while the code is such below:

```
if (b==0)
{
    c=1;
    s=0;
}

else if (abs(b)>abs(a))
{
    r=a/b;
    s=1/sqrt(1+r*r);
    c=r*s;
}

else
{
    r=b/a;
    s=1/sqrt(1+r*r);
    c=r*s;
}
```

I even changed the condition to:
if(abs(b)<0.001))
but again it didn't go in to this condition .
to avoid having NaN I changed the last `else` to : `else if(a!=0)`
and added a new else which was just the fist if. I mean:

```
if (b==0)
{
    c=1;
    s=0;
} else if (abs(b)>abs(a))
{
    r=a/b;
    s=1/sqrt(1+r*r);
    c=r*s;
}else if(a!=0)
{
    r=b/a;
    s=1/sqrt(1+r*r);
    c=r*s;
}else
{
    c=1;
    s=0;
}
```

but :1. it's not a good way(just a trick)    2. my final answer has bad errors (10^(-5))

now as a conclusion:1. I need to know why visual is OK with the same code that Matlab is not OK with?
2. what should I do? I'm in an emergency and I need a good way to compute QR decomposition of a matrix in C compatible with S function. or at least a good way to compute determinent of a matrix even if it's near singularity.

Comment: Take a look to [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), it the best decomposition library I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind that you are getting different results on visual studio and MATLAB (sfunction) is most probably the **behavior of your program is undefined**.
Condition `abs(b)>abs(a)` is wrong. `abs` expect an `int` type argument returns an `int`. As you defined `a` and `b` as `double` you should use `fabs`; expecting a `double` type argument and returns a `double` value.

```
else if (fabs(b) > fabs(a)){ ... }
```

Comment: thanks so much Haccks. U R my hero... :)
alhamdo le ALLAH it was just the answer. :D really helpful .
now my s function is OK but I have problems connecting to RTLAB which I will ask for an answer in another topic.

(I just started loving this site...)

Angeli O_o

Comment: JAZAK ALLAH HU KHAIR for your complement. :). Read [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) of Stack Overflow for more information. It will help you in future on SO.